# MySql - Query and combine different conditions

Tags: mysql

I actually struggled to come up with a decent title for my question.

I have a table that keeps a log of when users get to a level of a particular game. 
Levels go from 1 to 5 but I'm particularly interested in knowing how long they got stuck in **level 3** (for any game).

My table (gamehistorylog):

```
gameid (int)
level (int)
dateofchange (date)
```

I'm obviously not interested in games where the level is less than 3. 
I can use  `datediff()` but I'm not sure how to form the query to get the combined data of students that are at level 3 still (**how long have they been there?**) and those that passed it already at levels 4 & 5 (**how long did the spend in level 3**)? 
Every time a level is passed, a table record is generated with the new level and the date for the specific game.

Expected output is just a list of all games on the table that are at or above level 3 and time spent on level 3.

I have another table that keeps the official game status so i can join with that table and query the date of the most recent date for games where status = 3.

```
select l.gameid as gid,  
DATEDIFF(NOW(), max(dateofchange)) as datediff 
from gamehistorylog l 
join games g on g.gameid = l.gameid 
where g.status = 3 and l.level = 3 ;
```

This will get me the data for all instances where the highest level is 3. I don't know how to get it for those that already progressed to higher levels and then combine it all.

Comment: you should show some sample data and expected output.

Comment: It would be a lot easier to describe your requirement had you provided some sample input data and explained the logic based on this data set.

Comment: I just added some additional context, thank you.

Comment: Shouldn't the date diff be on the min() and max() of the dates at level 3? For all users that have a record at level 3?

Comment: Edit your question, and add some sample data rows, and the expected output from those rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select g.gameid as gid, datediff(curdate(), l.dateofchange) as datediff
from gamehistorylog l
join games g on g.gameid = l.gameid where l.level = 3 and g.status = 3
UNION
select a.gameid as gid, datediff(a.dateofchange, b.dateofchange) as datediff
from gamehistorylog a
join gamehistorylog b on a.gameid = b.gameid
where a.level = 4 and b.level = 3
```